# Array Object In Php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to store Student Object to array. and i try to do with below code. but it always show array count as 0

```
class Student
{
    $StudID = 0;
    $Name = null;
}
class Students
{
   static private $StudentData = array();
   static public function AddNewStudent($id,$name)
   {
    echo("AuctionID :".$AuctionID."<br/>");
        try{
            $objstd = new Student();
            $objstd->StuID = $id;
            $objstd->Name = &name;
            array_push($StudentData, $objstd);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
       {
            echo("Error".$e->getMessage());
       }
    }
    static public function TotalStudent()
    {
        return count($StudentData);
    }
}


Students::AddNewStudent(1,"name");
Students::AddNewStudent(2,"name2");
Students::AddNewStudent(3,"name3");
echo('Total auction running : '.Students::TotalStudent().'<br/>');
```

when i try to show array count it shows 0. i want to store all student data in static list
or then after when ever i want to see the list i get the list from static class only...

Comment: You actually don't need static here, you're probably looking for a global variable instead.

Comment: Thanx buddy your help is great. but actually i am trying to make a static class so i can use the same data between all visitors of website. but i cant achieve my goal with this static dont know what going on. But now i want to do something common data between all the visitors so plz give me some idea how to achieve the same.

Comment: Forget static. Static is not good. Will break. Make things hard. Often does not work. Bad idea static. Will make you hurt.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're creating a new array instead of referencing the one you declared. Use the `self` keyword to reference your static object property:

```
class Students
{
   static private $StudentData = array();
   static public function AddNewStudent($id,$name)
   {
    echo("AuctionID :".$AuctionID."<br/>");
        try{
            $objstd = new Student();
            $objstd->StuID = $id;
            $objstd->Name = &name;
            array_push(self::$StudentData, $objstd);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
       {
            echo("Error".$e->getMessage());
       }
    }
    static public function TotalStudent()
    {
        return count(self::$StudentData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In php you have to prefix [static variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) with `self::`, like this:

```
array_push(self::$StudentData, $objstd);
// and in count:

return count(self::$StudentData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why that complicated? Your `Student` class should take care of it's own, same for `Students`. Example:

```
$students = new Students();
$students[] = new Student(1, "name");
$students[] = new Student(2, "name2");
$students[] = new Student(3, "name3");
printf('Total auction running : %d.', count($students));
```

Example output:

```
Total auction running : 3.
```

The classes:

```
class Student
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}

class Students extends ArrayObject
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(array());
    }
    public function offsetSet($index, $newval) {
        if (!($newval instanceof Student)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('You can only add values of type Student.');
        }
        parent::offsetSet($index, $newval);
    }
}
```